# synchronized block on grails works on windows but no in linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, grails, synchronized

I have a grails application that relies on a synchronized block into a service.  When I run it on windows the synchronization works as expected but when I run on ams linux a get a StaleObjectStateException.

The problem is reproduced in the following example.

```
class TestService {

private final Object $lock = new Object[0];

TesteSync incrementa() {

    synchronized ($lock) {
        TesteSync t = TesteSync.findById(1)
        t.contador++
        t.save(flush: true)

        Thread.sleep(10000)

        return t
    }
}
```

}

In my understand, this exception occurs because multiple threads are trying to save the same object. That's why I'm using a synchronized block.

Linux java:

- java version "1.7.0_85"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.1.3.61.amzn1-x86_64 u85-b01)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

Windows java:

- java version "1.7.0_79"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess, maybe nothing will change: Can you try [installing the Oracle JDK on linux](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) too?

Comment: You are missing a try catch or a throws for InterruptedException

Comment: Are you sure you only have one instance of `TestService`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Spring should ensure that the service is a singleton under grails architecture. But I'll verify anyway

Comment: @BackSlash I'll give a try to Oracle JDK as well

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, just one instance

Comment: @BackSlash, Oracle didn't solve the problem neither :(

Comment: Try adding @transactional above incrementa call as a test you can do incrementa.withTransaction { inside before your find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about why you're getting the *StaleObjectStateException*.

If what you're looking for is pessimistic locking (allowing only one transaction access to the data at any given time), then you can use the domain class *lock()* method:

```
class TestService {
    static transactional = true

    TesteSync incrementa() {
        TesteSync t = TesteSync.lock(1)
        t.contador++
        return t.save()
    }
}
```

You can learn more about Grails pessimistic locking [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#locking).

PS: Grails services are transactional by default. But in my example I explicitly made the service transactional to call something to your attention: The lock is released by Grails automatically [when the transaction commits](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/lock.html). I also removed the flush because the data gets flushed when the transaction commits. If you were doing this from a controller method that's not explicitly set to *@Transactional*, then you would need the flush.

TIP: When you query by ID you can do this...

```
SomeDomainClass.get(1)
```

...instead of this...

```
SomeDomainClass.findById(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel Rosa the pessimistc locking approach worked! obrigado