# Handling StaleObjectException in Service

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, optimistic-locking

I have a scenario when an object gets updated by 2 different threads. Below is the code in grails service class. I am able to catch StaleObject exception but when I try to fetch it again from database and retry saving the value it doesn't work.

```
public long updateTimer(Long timeLeft, TestAttempted testAttempted){
    // Let's say testAttempted.version() is now 5
    // It is concurrently updated by other thread, version is now 6
    ........
    ............
    testAttempted.setTimer(someCalculatedValue)
    try{
        testAttempted.save(failOnError: true,flush:true) // StaleObject exception occurs
    }catch(OptimisticLockingFailureException e){
        testAttempted.refresh()
        testAttempted.setTimer(someCalculatedValue)
        testAttempted.save(failOnError:true)
    }
}
```

Why the above code doesn't update/save the value in catch block ? I also tried TestAttempted.get(id) method to fetch the latest one from database but it doesn't work.

But when I try this it updates the latest timer value:

In Controller:-

```
    try{
         timeLeft = assessmentService.updateTimer(timeLeft,testAttempted)
    }catch(OptimisticLockingFailureException e){
        testAttempted = TestAttempted.get(session['testAttemptedId'])
        ........
        testAttempted.setTimer(someCalculatedValue)
        testAttempted.save(failOnError: true)
    }
```

In service:

```
 public long updateTimer(Long timeLeft, TestAttempted testAttempted){
    ........
    .................
    testAttempted.setTimer(someValue)
    testAttempted.save(failOnError: true)
    return timeLeft
}
```

It doesn't work if it is thrown and handled both in controller/service. It works when it is thrown in service and handled in controller. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

The point is that you should always retry the entire transaction. Let the transaction be rolled back and repeat everything in a new one, because the old one is dirty (Hibernate session is invalid and there might be some uncommitted changes that are already flushed to the database).

Comment: Yeah! It makes sense. I also thought the same. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that when you do `refresh()` and then `save()` in the catch block, the instance of testAttempted is changed in between the refresh and save, and so it fails with the same exception, which now you are not catching, because it's in the catch block already.

The domains' `get()` method, afaik, is cached in the session, so TestAttempted.get(id) would return you the instance from the session and not the db.

`Merge()` is not necessary in this case, because you are manually setting the value after refresh and before save.

Using `Domain.lock()` can be a solution, but it would affect how you handle the TesttAttempted in other parts of the code, because now you may get a `CannotAcquireLock` exception in the places where you are trying to retrieve an instance and it is locked by this part of the code.

The question is - what is the conflict resolution strategy?  If it is 'last writer wins' - then just set `version= false` for the domain.  Or, you can use `TestAttemted.executeUpdate('set timer = .. where id = ..')` to update without increasing the version.

Im more complicated scenarios, consult Mark Palmer's in-depth coverage of the problem. http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2012/11/12/the-false-optimism-of-gorm-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually both the thread updates different field. They never update a common field. So I think dropping version field should be more appropriate. Isn't it ?

Comment: If you you do not have any other code that also update this Domain and rely on optimistic locking, then yes - just switch off the versioning for the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the retry approach is, how many retries is enough? Try this:

```
class AssessmentService {

    /*
     * Services are transactional by default.
     * I'm just making it explicit here. 
    */
    static transactional = true

    public long updateTimer(Long timeLeft, Long testAttemptedId) {
        def testAttempted = TestAttempted.lock(testAttemptedId)

        testAttempted.setTimer(someCalculatedValue)
        testAttempted.save()
    }
}
```

Pass a TestAttempted ID instead of an instance so that the service can retrieve the instance on its own, with its own transaction.

If you want to pass in the TestAttempted instance instead, I believe you  have to call testAttempted.[merge()](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html) within the service method before you make changes to the instance.

Here's similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835346/synchronized-block-on-grails-works-on-windows-but-no-in-linux/31841147#31841147).