# SQL data accessed concurrently - StaleObjectStateException

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm, concurrentmodification

```
class Document{
     hasMany{ changes: PendingChange}
}

class DocumentService{
     def acceptAll(){
        def owner = Document.get(params.id)
        def changes = owner.changes.findAll{it.status == "pending"}.collect{it.id}
        executorWrapperService.processClosure({
        changes.each{pc -> //*1 
                changeService.accept(pc)
            }
        }, owner)
        redirect(url: request.getHeader('referer'))

     }
}

class DocumentController{
    def index(){
        def result = [:]
        def owner = Document.get(params.id)
        //even if processing running, we want to show how many are left. Accept/Reject buttons will be disabled if processingpc is true
        result.changes = owner.changes.findAll{it.status == "pending"}
        if(executorWrapperService.hasRunningProcess(owner)){ //*2
          result.processingpc = true
        }
        .
        .
        .
        return result
    }
}

class ExecutorWrapperService {

    def executorService
    ConcurrentHashMap<Object,java.util.concurrent.FutureTask> activeFuture = [:]

    def processClosure(clos,owner){
        owner = "${owner.class.name}:${owner.id}"
        //see if we got a process running for owner already
        def existingFuture = activeFuture.get(owner)
        if(!existingFuture){
            //start new thread and store the process
              def future = executorService.submit(clos as java.util.concurrent.Callable)
              activeFuture.put(owner,future)
        }else{
            //if a previous process for this owner is done, remove it and start new one
            if(existingFuture.isDone()){
                activeFuture.remove(owner)
                processClosure(clos,owner)
            }
            //if not done, do something else
        }
    }

    def hasRunningProcess(owner){
        owner = "${owner.class.name}:${owner.id}"
        // There is no process running for this owner
        if(activeFuture.get(owner) == null){
            return false
        // there was a process, but now its done.
        }else if(activeFuture.get(owner).isDone()){
            activeFuture.remove(owner)
            return false
        // we have a running process
        }else if(activeFuture.get(owner).isDone() == false){
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

The above code demonstrates what is happening. On my index screen I display a list of changes. When the user clicks `accept all` button, the `DocumentService.acceptAll` is called. Then a new thread is created and the changes start applying. This has effect on database objects. The request is redirected to `index`. Because I want to disable any actions on pending changes while the processing is happening, `ExecutorWrapperService.activeFuture` is used to tell the DocumentController if there is processing happening for that document. When executing the `DocumentController.index` I only read database fields for display, no writes are happening.

When performing the above action, occasionally I get one of the following errors:

```
events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [Document#1495]
```

On line *1 , or the same error on line *2. 
I believe this is a problem to do with the thread that I am creating. 
I am trying to figure how I should use transactions or sessions to solve this, but havent made it yet.

Comment: Can we see the code where you are actually saving the changes in Document?

Comment: I can add some of it tomorrow, but it is quite complicated to go in full. What I noticed though, is that if I stop accessing the owner.changes (above *2), both errors stop.

Comment: Regarding the StaleObjectStateException, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835346/synchronized-block-on-grails-works-on-windows-but-no-in-linux/31841147#31841147  Have you considered using Gpars framework (http://www.gpars.org/guide/) to handle the concurrency?